# Folders opening in a new window when double clicking in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

I'm using Windows Vista Ultimate, and when I double click on a Folder in Windows Explorer, instead of just opening it, it opens a new window.

I already checked in Tools -> Options, and "Open each folder in the same window" is selected.

What is going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect a program overriding, have you installed any tweaking programs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two registry tweaks that will change this behaviour copy the code into a new file named as below.

`settingsownwindow.reg` (will open folder in new windows):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CabinetState]
"Settings"=hex:0c,00,02,00,3b,01,e7,77,60,00,00,00
"FullPath"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoSaveSettings"=dword:00000000
```

`settingssamewindow.reg` (will open folder in same window):

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CabinetState]
"Settings"=hex:0c,00,02,00,1b,01,e7,77,60,00,00,00
"FullPath"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoSaveSettings"=dword:00000000
```

Original answer (with fixed link) below.

---

**[Kelly's Korner](http://web.archive.org/web/20080220235605/http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm)**, #209 right

Comment: Wow, you rock,  thanks. I can't believe I had to edit the registry for that, though. Thanks!!!
I'd vote you up, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: I'll upvote, since I was almost posting: this can't be fixed +1 Molly!